# No module name jsonpickle even though its installed in the correct folder

Tags: python, web, virtualenv

I have tried to run my python app on my website, but I get the error

"No module named jsonpickle"

even though I have jsonpickle installed. I even found the file path, and jsonpickle is there, but still my app says "no module named jsonpickle"

i logged into the SSH and typed

```
source /home/dsmproto/virtualenv/main.py/3.8/bin/activate && cd /home/dsmproto/main.py
```

then i installed all of the modules i needed, specifically

```
pip install jsonpickle
```

and then i go to run my app and i get the error:

```
    stdin: is not a tty
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 369, in <module>
    app_module = load_app()
  File "/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 76, in load_app
    return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
  File "/home/dsmproto/main.py/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from main import main as application
  File "/home/dsmproto/main.py/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from wallet import wallet
  File "/home/dsmproto/main.py/wallet.py", line 3, in <module>
    from blockchain_utils import blockchain_utils
  File "/home/dsmproto/main.py/blockchain_utils.py", line 3, in <module>
    import jsonpickle
ImportError: No module named jsonpickle
```

Is that enough info for you guys?

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Installed in "the" virtualenv? There is no such thing as "the" virtualenv. There are many. Please give details on how you configured "my website" to use "the virtualenv". This question needs a lot more info.

Comment: Im super new to this, so idk what else you need, but i have the module installed where it needs to be, but somehow my app still says there module doesnt exists, even though i know it does

Comment: Please show exactly how you're installing modules (I mean the *exact* command(s) and such), and how exactly you're running scripts. Clearly you're not running scripts from the environment you're installing modules to, so we need to know what you're currently doing so we can point out what needs changing.

Comment: Yeah, ill update the question

Comment: Naming a directory main.py is quite confusing. I first thought you'd try to `cd` into a file... How do you run the app?

Comment: yeah, you're right about the naming, but the app is run by my main.py file in that main.py directory. The app gets started, that's not the issue. The issue is it says there's no jsonpickle module. I have literally checked everything, and even gone back and uninstalled and reinstalled it, and checked the correct directory for it, but my app still can't find it. How can i see where my app is checking for the module?

Comment: Show us the output of this command `pip show jsonpickle` and also the output of this code running inside your app `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Answer (score 0):

Im super new on this topic - sorry if not so precise.

I faced a similar issue installing jsonpickle - (virtual environment in Windows 10 / PyCharm). Even after installation ("pip install jsonpickle") I was getting the message "No module named jsonpickle" when I tried (import jsonpickle).

I solved that by clicking on jsonpickle (right mouse button) and forcing the importation of the module - after that, it passed to be recognized.